# VB6 and Sql server 2016 Express connection string

Tags: vb6, sql-server-2016-express

In one of our old vb6 app connection string is as follows:

```
nk = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;"
nk = nk + "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
nk = nk + "Persist Security Info=False;"
nk = nk + "User ID=sa;"
nk = nk + "Password=******;"
nk = nk + "Initial Catalog=" & db & ";"
nk = nk + "Data Source=" & hn
kon.ConnectionString = nk
kon.Open
```

If I try to connect with these options it wont work, so I'm interested why these two options:

```
nk = nk + "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
nk = nk + "Persist Security Info=False;"
```

are not ignored?

Just to mention that application is connecting to Sql Server 2016 Express on Windows Server 2016 Standard over local network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your issue is with

> Integrated Security=SSPI

It should be set to false (or removed altogether) as you are not using current Windows user Authentication but a standard SQL user-password login.

Out of [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When false, User ID and Password are specified in the connection. When
>   true, the current Windows account credentials are used for
>   authentication. Recognized values are true, false, yes, no, and sspi
>   (strongly recommended), which is equivalent to true. **If User ID and
>   Password are specified and Integrated Security is set to true, the
>   User ID and Password will be ignored** and Integrated Security will be
>   used.

Comment: ... and that means that my domain account doesn't have privileges to access sql server db. thanks for the tip.